# RRSR Sorting i got "a sort expression for the tablix4 includes an aggregate function"

Tags: sorting, ssrs-2008, grouping, reporting-services

i add you my view of my report

[a busy cat http://s3.subirimagenes.com:81/imagen/previo/thump_7631306captura.png](http://s3.subirimagenes.com:81/imagen/previo/thump_7631306captura.png)

You can see that the group parent is NOM CLIENTE (ACCOUNT) after it has a
child group called fecha(date) after every fecha(date) has a few pro
code (product code), and every pro code has a cantidad(quantity), and
every (pro codigo * cantidad) (product code * quantity) has its
importe(amount) so, every fecha(date) has its importe (its total
quantity bought that day) now every client has a total quantity (all
his/her purchases) and now i want to sort my report but this last
total quantity, you could see

```
837,25000
549,60000
1004,0000
369,50000
464,50000
```

the order should be:

```
1004,0000
837,25000
549,60000
464,50000
369,50000
```

when i do a sorting on the upper left corner and i put this function on the sort tab

`=Sum(Fields!importe.Value)`

i get this message:

> an error ocurred during local report processing. the definition of the
>   report /best_accounts is invalid A sort expression for the tablix
>   'Tablix4' includes an aggregate function. Aggregate functions cannot
>   be used in data row sort expressions.

then how can i sorted as i want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- go to the matrix proprieties
- select the group's tab
- select the group's row and edit it
- you should see a sorting tab.
- enter the total expression and select ASC or DESC

Answer (score 0):

A sort expression for the tablix ‘Tablix3’ uses the function RowNumber. RowNumber cannot be used in sort expressions.